# Enhancement for HTML Drag and Drop upload file?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, upload, drag-and-drop

I know this question is a bit naive, but I think it's good to put it on here anyway.

I have a HTML drag and drop upload file. My question is that if it is possible that when user clicks on the droparea (beside normal behavior drag and drop file to droparea) and the select file dialog opened and when user selects files, we can call the drop events and start the process of normal drag and drop.

Is it possible or has anyone done or thought of that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had some success by binding to drop events on a input element.

See the jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/LPVcM/

Good luck!

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="instructions">Drag a file here.</div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var container = document.getElementById('container'),
    file = null,
    instructions = document.getElementById('instructions');

addFileInput();

function addFileInput() {
    var el = document.createElement('input');
    el.setAttribute('type', 'file');
    el.setAttribute('class', 'fileinput');
    el.addEventListener('drop', function() {
        instructions.innerHTML += ' Thanks!';
    });
    el.addEventListener('change', function() {
        instructions.innerHTML += ' Yum!';
    el.className += ' hidden'
        addFileInput();
    });
    container.appendChild(el);
}
```

**CSS**

```
.fileinput {
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    opacity: 0;
}

.fileinput.hidden {
    display: none;
}

#instructions {
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
}

#container {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: it's clever that you enlarged the input button and hid it, so user can have the feeling that they actually click and open the dialog, but only in "right area" :D. Anyway, thanks, I've developed something else based on your solution :)